# error setting virtualhosts in xampp

Tags: apache, xampp, virtualhost

I have read a lot of articles and posts about Virtual Hosts setting but I was not able to figure out which is the problem.

I have a Win7 pc where I installed an xampp to manage my php + mysql projects.
As per default the web root directory is C:\xampp\htdocs
To avoid conflict with skype I setted apache to work on port 8080

If I browse to something like localhost:8080/mysubdir it works fine.

My idea was now to point the webroot of Apache to another dir on my pc: the dir where I would like to point my webroot is C:\Users\myuser\Google Drive\CODE_REPOS

I searched on-line and it seems to be possible by VirtualHost;
Here my configuration

```
apache httpd.conf
#Listen [::]:80
Listen *:8080

# Virtual hosts
#Include "conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf"
```

here my httpd-vhosts.conf

```
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:8080
#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs" # change this line with your htdocs folder
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost development.loc:8080>
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/Users/myuser/Google Drive/CODE_REPOS" # change this line with your htdocs folder
    ServerName development.loc
    ServerAlias development.loc
    <Directory "C:/Users/myuser/Google Drive/CODE_REPOS">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now the code in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
    127.0.0.1       localhost
    127.0.0.1       development.loc
```

If I stop Apache, uncomment the line #Include "conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf" and try to start Apache again, it start and stop immediatly.

I don't understand what I missed.

Comment: Have you checked your Apache logs?

Answer (score 0):

remove the hash from the start of the include line

```
    apache httpd.conf
    #Listen [::]:80
    Listen *:8080

    # Virtual hosts
    include "conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf"
```